# Applying aggregation function over large numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

I am trying to calculate a mean value across large numpy array. Originally, I tried:

```
data = (np.ones((10**6, 133))
        for _ in range(100))
np.stack(data).mean(axis=0)
```

but I was getting

> numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate xxx GiB for an array with shape (100, 1000000, 133) and data type float32

In the original code data is a generator of more meaningful vectors.

I thought about using dask for such an operation, hoping it will split my data into chunks backed by disk.

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

data = (np.ones((10**6, 133)) for _ in range(100))
x = da.stack(da.from_array(arr, chunks="auto") for arr in data)
x = da.mean(x, axis=0)
y = x.compute()
```

However, when I run it, the process terminates with "Killed".

How can I resolve this issue on a single machine?

Comment: The average is `1`. Jokes aside, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365119/mean-value-and-standard-deviation-of-a-very-huge-data-set) will interest you.

Comment: @Ivan I lack :haha icon on SO. Thanks.

Comment: @dzieciou You are getting this error while stacking the arrays ?

Comment: @MSS Yes., while stacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
agg_sum = np.zeros((10**6, 133))
total = 100

for dt in data:
    agg_sum = agg_sum + dt
_mean = agg_sum/total
```

Comment: Great solution! Works faster than my solution and requires less disk space. Two things I would add: (1) `del dt` to avoid runing out of memory, (2) replace `len(data)` with some `total` integer: the total number of arrays to average is known in advance, but you cannot `len` over generator.

Comment: I also didn't know the shape of single array (`dt`) so I initialized `agg_sum = 0 ` and it works great as well.

Comment: @dzieciou I know we can't take the `len` over generator. I just wanted to show the approach.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution I found is to store all arrays in disk-backed file, using [`numpy.memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

```
import numpy as np

total = 100
shape = (10 ** 6, 133)
c = np.memmap(
    "total.array", dtype="float64", mode="w+", shape=(total, *shape), order="C"
)
for idx, arr in enumerate(data):
    c[idx,:,:] = arr[:]
    del arr
    
c.mean(axis=0)
```

The important thing here is to `del arr` to avoid using whole memory before garbage collector reclaims unused arrays.

Note, the solution requires around 100GB of disk space, while the solution of @MSS requires much less space by keeping only the current sum.